# error 10054 while trying to download binary file through ftp in python 2.7

Tags: python, ftp

I'm pretty new to python, so this very well be user error here, but I'm not quite sure what to do from here.

I'm trying to login to a zyxel gs2200 switch via ftp and download it's config file.

The command through cmd ftp is

`get config X.log`  where X.log is whatever you decide to name it.

In python I can log in just fine, but I can not download a file without throwing an exception.

```
 import ftplib
 ftp = ftplib.FTP("my.ip.here")
 ftp.login('user','Pass') 

'230 Logged in'

ftp.retrbinary('RETR config', open('config', 'wb').write)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>

File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 398, in retrbinary
    self.voidcmd('TYPE I')

File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 248, in voidcmd
    self.putcmd(cmd)

File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 178, in putcmd
    self.putline(line)

File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 173, in putline
    self.sock.sendall(line)

File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 222, in meth
   return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)

error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I've also tried opening a file before and then just calling it in the method, but it still gives the same error.

does anyone have any idea on how I can get these config files in python?

Comment: 10054 is `E_CONN_RESET` and is probably the most common error you get in comms programs.  It is usually caused by a network issue.

Answer (score 0):

I Can tell you easy method to do this.

Ftp Login Url: ftp://username:password@hostname/

Username: your Username

Password: Your Password

To download a file from FTP server you could:

```
import urllib 
urllib.urlretrieve('ftp://username:password@hostname/yourconfigname', 'yourconfigname')
```

In your case you can do something like this.

===============================================================

As for your problem the python error clearly indicating that you did not establish connection correctly(Always Close Connection) or May be your destination had already connected to maximum destinations thats why your target destination closing your connection.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would not be correctly connecting though. I can use the cmd ftp right after that and connect and download without issue.